# Gadzooks! Architectures abound! Looking for an embedded processor/controller taxonomy

Tags: microcontroller, taxonomy, microprocessors, embedded

I am looking for a taxonomy of embedded processors. Which processors belong to which families? Who decends from whom?

Does anyone here know of a simple article that describes it?

Answer (score 1):

The [Common Microcontrollers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_common_microcontrollers) page on Wikipedia may be a place to start, or [this shorter list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcontroller#Types_of_microcontrollers) in the Microcontrollers article.

Answer (score 0):

[Instructables](http://www.instructables.com/id/ESICJ1VA2EEWIJKVP2/) has a nice overview.

Comment: I'm looking for a much more detailed review. E.g., the 8051 as compared to the 8080, or the Z80 versus the 8008, and which mainframe architectures influenced them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a taxonomy for categorizing the many very different kinds of processors, you may like ["What are different types of computer architectures?"](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4185/what-are-different-types-of-computer-architectures).

If you want historical information on the influence of one processor on another,
you may like

- ["Computer Chronology"](http://longstreet.typepad.com/thesciencebookstore/computer-chronology-short.html)
- ["The 11 Most Influential Microprocessors of All Time"](http://www.pcworld.com/article/171171/the_11_most_influential_microprocessors_of_all_time.html)
- ["25 Microchips That Shook the World"](http://spectrum.ieee.org/semiconductors/processors/25-microchips-that-shook-the-world/0) and the sequel, ["More Earthshaking Chips"](http://spectrum.ieee.org/semiconductors/devices/the-runnersup-more-earthshaking-chips/0)
- ["Intel's CPU family trees"](http://cpucharts.wallsoferyx.net/intelall.html) ( [mirror](http://cpucharts.info/)  ?)